# quiero ingresar numeros entre 0 a 20 y que salga un mensaje diciendo nros fuera del intervalo si es que no se cumple pero usando excepciones

Tags: java

```
package excepciones;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class excepcion2 {
      static void rango(int num)throws calcular
      {
            if((num>20)||(num<0)){
                throw new calcular("Números fuera del intervalo");
            }
      }  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws calcular
    {
        Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;

        try {
        System.out.println("Ingrese un nro entre 0 y 20");
        n=entrada.nextInt();
        rango(n);
            }
        catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Ingrese caracteres numericos");
        } 
    }
    public class calcular extends Exception
    {   
    public calcular()
    {}
    public calcular(String msj_error)
    {
        super(msj_error);
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Alonso, es importante que leas  [ask] para que tengas información acerca de como realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida 
en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Vale primero no te funcionaba porque tienes una clase interna la cual es una clase para hacer una excepcion y la intentas llamar desde un metodo statico. entonces has de cambiar eso y la llamada desde el metodo main al no ser un metodo estatico de la clase tienes que crear una instancia de la clase.
Por cierto los nombre de clases y metodos deben ser autodocumentados , los tuyos dan lugar a errores ya que la clase que estiende de exception se llama calcular y no calcula nada es una excepcion luego la clase principal se llama excepcion2 , no es una clase que extienda de exception..... incomprensible jajaja aqui la solucion aaa y tambien capturas una excepcion MIstMatchException o algo asi jajaja q nunca sera lanzada es decir sobra, tambien lanzas la excepcion que creas en el metodo main y a la vez tambien la capturas con un metodo try-catch eso es un error grave, ademas el metodo main nunca debe lanzar las excepciones :

public class PruebadeExcepciones {

```
  public void validarRango(int num)throws ExcepcionRango
  {
        if((num>20)||(num<0)){

            throw new ExcepcionRango("No esta en el intervalo");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Esta comprendido en el intervalo");
        }
  } 
  public class ExcepcionRango extends Exception
  {   


      public ExcepcionRango(String msj_error)
      {
          super(msj_error);
      }
    }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;


    System.out.println("Ingrese un nro entre 0 y 20");
    n=entrada.nextInt();
    try {
        PruebadeExcepciones objetoClase=new PruebadeExcepciones();
        objetoClase.validarRango(n);
    } catch (ExcepcionRango e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

  }
```

}

Comment: gracias por la ayuda alex ,pero tengo esta duda al mostrar el resultado por pantalla sale todo esto: excepciones.excepcion4$Excepcionrango: Nro fuera del intervalo , yo solo quiero que salga :Nro fuera del intervalo hay alguna manera de mostrar solo esa parte?

Comment: Si la manera de hacerlo es, en el constructor de la clase q extiende a exception, en vez de llamar al padre (super) y mandarle un mensaje, ese metodo es el q por defecto te pinta todo eso, si lo cambias por System.out.println(mensaje) ya no saldra esa informacion , solo el mensaje. ;) Es decir cambiar esto:   public class ExcepcionRango extends Exception
  {   


      public ExcepcionRango(String msj_error)
      {
          super(msj_error);
      }
    }   por esto: 
      public ExcepcionRango(String msj_error)
      {
          System.out.println(msj_error);
      }
    }